Microsoft Excel 365 VBA - Inserting Image into Table via UserForm
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Add "Image", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            ' file has been selected

            ' e.g. show path in textbox
           ' Me.Label9.Text = .SelectedItems(1)

            ' e.g. display preview image in an image control
            Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
            Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
        Else
            ' user aborted the dialog

        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Job Sheets Active
Worksheets("PartDB").Activate

'Determine Empty Row
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Enter Data from Form into Table
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = PartNumber.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Description.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MatBox1.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = ThickBox.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = FinishBox.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ProcessBox1.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = KitNumber.Value
'Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 8).Shapes.AddPicture =



Unload Me
End Sub

Good morning,
For the life of me, I have been struggling to get the selected Picture from the userform to insert into the Table alongside the other values.
Every other aspect works flawlessly but I've tried several ways to get the selected image to insert, I either get the code value of the image or an error message.
So I select the image via the UserForm, all details are filled out and when the Command Button is clicked I want to insert all that information into a table with the Image.
I can get all text based info to insert except the image. As you can see I have commented out the last insertion as it's been frustrating me for a while.

SOLVED!
Many headaches later, solution comes from a function I didn't even know existed.
Was talking to one of the many brains amongst our company and someone suggested I use the InsertPictureInCell function.
See Below:
Option Explicit
Dim fpath As String, PicPath As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x As Integer
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    x = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    If x <> 0 Then
    fpath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fpath)
    Image1.PictureSizeMode = 1
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim rCl As Range
Dim lx As Long
Dim Y As Worksheet
Dim myPic As Object

'Make Job Sheets Active
Worksheets("PartDB").Activate

'Determine Empty Row
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Enter Data from Form into Table
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = PartNumber.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Description.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MatBox1.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = ThickBox.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = FinishBox.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ProcessBox1.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = KitNumber.Value
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 8).Select
Worksheets("PartDB").Cells(emptyRow, 8).InsertPictureInCell (fpath)

    
Unload Me
End Sub

